# Unable load google map by javascript? Of course I don't have an API key. but usually it shows for a second

Tags: javascript

**JS Code**

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

                function loadMap() {
                    console.log('ji');
                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(17.412630, 78.447480);
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: position
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("divami_location"), myOptions);
                    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                        position: position, 
                        map: map,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        title:"Software Private Limited",
                    });
                }

    </script>
```

**HTML code**

```
            <a href="#contact" id="maps" onclick="loadMap()"><div>Contact</div></a>
```

when I click console shows an error, that is, **js:93 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined**
Please help me to solve this

Comment: There is no any `addEventListener` call in the code you provided.

Comment: but still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Get a key! Here is why and how:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#specify-a-key-when-loading-the-api

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors.